# BitBucket Node.js Pipeline Environment Variables

Tags: node.js, git, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

This may be a stupid question, but is there a standard/best way to control the environments when deploying through a pipeline (for instance to Heroku).
I have a Node.js app and, for instance, I use 'nodemon' in the "npm start" script I specify in my 'package.json' in dev, but need it to run just 'node' in production when I deploy it.
How do I go about making that change programmatically when I deploy via the pipeline?

I hope that makes sense, thanks in advance!